# My wife disappeared, but we're still married. How can I fix this?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-comes-alive

I accidentally ran my world without Minecraft Comes Alive and my wife disappeared. I re-opened the world with the mod enabled and it says I'm already married but she isn't anywhere to be found.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried using the whistle? Did you try the kill all entities command?

Answer (score 4):

When you disable/remove any mod, the game will just delete all entities, blocks, etc from gamefile, because it does not know them. However you normally need to run `/fml confirm` command, so you cannot do it by accident (in singleplayer mode you need to confirm the world load).

However this can be no thing when such a mod does not add any own things, just modifies the already existing ones (villager entity in this case). Therefore the game can probably start without such a warning. Then it will find a villager with strange NBT it cannot recognize and instead of possible crash, it just deletes that entity.

Therefore **your wife was deleted for good** (with really high certainty), if the mod does not store those data in some additional external ways (such as database or written in it's own file). Which is not a thing if I looked into the code careful enough. BUT if there is any item ingame that can bring you your wife even from distant positions or other dimensions, there MIGHT be something that stores the entity so it can work. However it can also only store the "link" to already deleted entity (as mentioned above), then no luck here.

Therefore you need to fix this thing so you can marry again. Probably **the best idea** is to use inbuilt **command** for it:

```
/mca rm <username>
```

- Reset username's marriage

However if that won't work, you can still:

- edit NBT tags via some NBT editor (BUT you NEED to know what are you exactly doing)
- place all inventory etc into chest and then delete your player's data from world directory, then it will reset (however everything else will reset as well, which is not kinda gentle)

Answer (score 1):

This has happened to me before and i just go to a cleric (or if you can’t find one then just get a villager editor from your inventory or make one) and hit special then hit divorce spouse and you’ll be divorced.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this problem would be to go on run>%appdata%>minecraft>saves>(MAPNAME)>data and delete the thing that says minecraftcomesalive.dat But warning this will delete all of your progress in this mod.